# Is it possible to add an admin page using add_submenu_page() and pass a var in the query string?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, admin-menu, query-string

I am making a plugin and I have a bunch of different data types that I am creating edit pages for. I'd rather not have to create a separate function to add each one to the admin menus, since they're all using the same function to display their edit page. I have tried:

```
`add_submenu_page('upload_manage', "Programs", "Programs", 'manage_options', 'manage-data&type=program', "manage_data");`
```

(note the `&type=program` -- that's what I want to work). It adds the correct link that I was trying for to the admin submenu, but when I click the menu item, I get kicked out to the dashboard with the `&C=1` URL. Is there any way to do this? Or am I going to have to create 7 different functions that all call the same function to display the edit page.. i.e. `manage_programs` `manage_schedule` `manage_otherstuff` etc...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your menu slug (5th parameter) can't be the same across multiple pages, and it obviously can't have an & in it, but you can have all the pages you want call the same callback function (the last param).

```
add_submenu_page('upload_manage', "Programs", "Programs", 'manage_options', 'manage-programs', "manage_data");
add_submenu_page('upload_manage', "Schedule", "Schedule", 'manage_options', 'manage-schedule', "manage_data");
```

Then in the manage_data function, check the value of $_GET['page'] for the slug and act accordingly.